# Sequences, limits of proportions and functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(C_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of finite discrete sets $C_n$ of increasing size. Consider sequences $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty, (B_n)_{n=1}^\infty,$ of proper subsets $A_n \subset B_n \subset C_n$ with $\#(C_n \setminus B_n) = O(1)$ and satisfying $\#A_n /\#B_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ while $\#B_n - \#A_n > \sqrt{\#B_n}$. For a function $f_n : C_n \to C_n$ and an element $c_n \in f_n(B_n)$, denote
$$
P_n(f_n ; c_n) := \dfrac{\# \{\alpha \in A_n \mid f_n(\alpha) = c_n\}}{\# \{\alpha \in B_n \mid f_n(\alpha) = c_n\}}.
$$
**Question:** Can we find a sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of (well-defined) functions $f_n : C_n \to C_n$ simultaneously satisfying the following two conditions?

(i) For every sequence $(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of elements $c_n \in f_n(B_n)$, we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n(f_n ; c_n) = 1;
$$

(ii) For every sequence $(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of elements $c_n \in f_n(B_n)$, we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1 - P_n(f_n ; c_n)}{1 - \#A_n / \# B_n} \neq 1.
$$
Thanks!